# How do I get a browser button to display in Internet Explorer using Crossrider?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, crossrider

We are a small UK charity and a local web design company has built us a browser extension using Crossrider. Our problem is the browser icon does not display in IE, it is fine in Firefox and Chrome. They have been unable to find what is wrong. Unfortunately, I am a JavaScript novice. However when I looked at the background.js file I think something has been coded wrong. There is reference to images for Chrome and Firefox but not IE but my understanding of Crossrider is that you only need to have a single reference and not specify individual browsers? We would really appreciate anyone's help on what is probably a simple question.

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {

if(appAPI.browser.name == "firefox") {
    appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon('tiny_icon_23.png');
} else if(appAPI.browser.name == "chrome") {
    appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon('tiny_icon_24.png');
} else {
    appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon('tiny_icon_23.png');
}

appAPI.browserAction.setPopup({
    resourcePath:'popup.html',
    width: 366,
    height: 207
});
```

Comment: Following the logic in the example provided, the button image is set specifically for Firefox and Chrome, and in the _else_ clause for all other browsers including IE. Hence, the code is reasonable and at first glance should work on IE. However, there are many reasons why an icon may not appear in IE, foremost of which is an error in the background code. Additionally, there may be other reasons and hence it's best to provide the **extension id** so that the cause can be properly investigated. [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Also, make sure you've enabled the browser button for IE in the extension config — you probably did, yet as the buttons are enabled separately for each browser, it is possible to miss it.